# How to sum a value in a joined table only once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

```
ID CUST ORDER
=============
1    1    1
2    1    1
3    1    1

ID CUST PARTS1 PARTS2
=====================
1    1    5      3
```

What I want in returns is

```
CUST ORDERS PARTS
=================
  1    3     8
```

The select that I'm currently using is

```
SELECT Distinct(o.cust), 
    orders=sum(order), 
    parts=sum(p.parts1 + p.parts2) 
FROM orders as o 
left join parts p on o.cust = p.cust
GROUP BY o.cust
```

The problem is the parts are summed for every row in the order table for that customer. Instead of 8 parts I get 24 (3*8)

How can I come up with the correct value for parts?

UPDATE: I want all of the rows in the first table. So I want to see all of the orders even when the customer doesn't have any parts in the second table.

Comment: How did you get `3` for Orders ?

Comment: In the first table there are 3 rows and I'm summing up the order column.

Comment: It looks like XY problem. The schema and data are meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Do the aggregation first and then the join:

```
SELECT o.cust, o.orders, 
       sum(p.parts1 + p.parts2) as parts
FROM (select o.cust, sum(order) as orders
      from orders  o 
      group by o.cust
     ) o left join
     parts p
     on o.cust = p.cust
GROUP BY o.cust, o.orders;
```

Comment: I thought of that but I need all of the rows in the first table even when there are no rows in the second table.

Comment: @Gary . . . I have no idea what your comment is referring to.  In your question, the "first" table has three rows, but the output only one.  This will return all *customers* in the first table, each on his/her own row.

Comment: @GordonLinoff If we need to apply where codition for orders table in that case should we apply in the inner query or in the outer query or at both places?

Comment: @VikasChauhan . . . The `orders` table is only processed once, in the subquery.  So, conditions on that table would be in thesubquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table t1(id int,cust int, [order] int)
go
create table t2(id int,cust int,parts1 int,parts2 int)
go

insert t1 values(1,1,1)
insert t1 values(2,1,1)
insert t1 values(3,1,1)
insert t1 values(4,2,1)
go
insert into t2 values(1,1,5,3)
go

select * from t1 
select * from t2 

select a.cust ,a.orders,isnull(b.parts1,0) +isnull(b.parts2,0)   from 
    (select cust ,SUM([order] ) as orders from t1 group by cust  ) a
    left join t2 b on a.cust =b.cust
```